# Group list of dicts by two params and count grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have list of dicts with id numbers, I need to group it by `main_id` and `second_id` and count values in each group. What is the best Python way to reach this?

I'm tried with Pandas, but don't get dict with groups and counts

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df2 = df.groupby('main_id').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('main_id')['second_id']).to_dict()
print(df2)
```

List looks like:

```
[
    {
        "main_id":34,
        "second_id":"2149"
    },
    {
        "main_id":82,
        "second_id":"174"
    },
    {
        "main_id":24,
        "second_id":"4QCp"
    },
    {
        "main_id":34,
        "second_id":"2149"
    },
    {
        "main_id":29,
        "second_id":"126905"
    },
    {
        "main_id":34,
        "second_id":"2764"
    },
    {
        "main_id":43,
        "second_id":"16110"
    }
]
```

I need result like:

```
[
{
    "main_id":43,
    "second_id":"16110",
    "count": 1
},
{
    "main_id":34,
    "second_id":"2149",
    "count": 2
}
]
```

Comment: Have you looked at `itertools.groupby` yet?

Comment: @chepner `groupby()` groups consecutive elements in the same group. Unless she sorts the list first, the groups won't be consecutive.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, and that's specifically mentioned in the documentation for `groupby`. I never said something simple like `groupby(the_list)` was the answer.

Comment: You could convert the list to a pandas dataframe and use its grouping and counting methods.

Comment: @Barmar can you show example?

Comment: No, that would be free coding.

Comment: @Barmar can you check my pandas code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `collections` (from the standard library) instead of pandas.  I assigned the list of dicts to `xs`:

```
import collections

# create a list of tuples; each is (main_id, secondary_id)
ids = [ (x['main_id'], x['second_id']) for x in xs ]

# count occurrences of each tuple
result = collections.Counter(ids)
```

Finally, `result` is a dict, which can be readily converted to the final form (not shown).

```
Counter({(34, '2149'): 2,
         (82, '174'): 1,
         (24, '4QCp'): 1,
         (29, '126905'): 1,
         (34, '2764'): 1,
         (43, '16110'): 1})
```